# How to reference MSI files in a different folder when executing msiexec.exe command in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer

I have written a windows batch script to install some MSI files where all my MSI files were in the same folder as the batch script and I was using "%~dp0" to refer to the path of my MSI files. This was the command I was using before and works fine:

```
msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0TestMSI.msi" ALLUSERS=1 REINSTALLMODE=vomus /lv*v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\TestInstall.log" /qn
```

But now I am trying to store all the MSI files in a separate folder and trying to access them using the same msiexec.exe command. Also, I am not supposed to use the full file path of the MSI(for ex: "C:/Test/MSIs/TestMSI.msi") as that location may change in the future and that will break my script.

I though this would work but it doesn't work:

```
msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0..\MSIs\TestMSI.msi" ALLUSERS=1 REINSTALLMODE=vomus /lv*v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\TestInstall.log" /q
```

Is there any way where I can reference the MSI file in a different folder(in this case "MSIs" folder) in the msiexec.exe command? I tried many ways and went through documentations but none of them was successful.

Comment: Yes right. For more clarity, filepath for one of the MSI files will be "C:\Test\MSIs\Test.msi" and the batch script will be  "C:\Test\Scripts\batch.cmd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pushd` to the directory and reset your `/i` path to just the file name:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0..\MSIs"
msiexec.exe /i "TestMSI.msi" ALLUSERS=1 REINSTALLMODE=vomus /lv*v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\TestInstall.log" /q
popd
```

Comment: Wow, thank you Gerhard, this worked very well. :)